# Box2D‑2.3.2‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl Error

Tags: pip, box2d

I want to upload Box2D‑2.3.2‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl to my 3.9 python loaded mac. It always gives me this ERROR: Box2D‑2.3.2‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel filename. I write the code "pip install Box2D‑2.3.2‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl". So what should you offer to do. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

`win` in the whl filename stands for windows, so you do not have the correct whl file for your platform. You need to grab a macos labeled whl file from Pypi

Comment: I gives me the following warnings ; python3 -m pip install "Box2D"
.....
Boremissing -w201 -globals b2Globals -outdir library/Box2D -keyword -w511 -D_SWIG_KWARGS -o Box2D/Box2D_wrap.cpp Box2D/Box2D.i
      error: command 'swig' failed: No such file or directory
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> Box2D

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Comment: I trid to download from https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-pypi.. Thank you very much for your reply

Comment: another try.=)     Specifications:

  - pybox2d -> python[version='2.7.*|3.3.*|3.4.*|3.5.*']

Your python: python=3.9

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.